# QlikView: Disable Element Reorganization in List Box

Tags: qlikview

I have a filed 'Day_NAM' (contains the names of the days in the week) and a field 'Day_Order' (numeric field, gives each day a number (monday=1, Tuesday=2 etc) so I can sort the days).
I managed to sort the days in the list box the way i wanted. However, when I make selection on the list box, the days change their positions in the list box. What it has to be done so that the elements in the list box do not change position when a user makes selections?

Link to the QVW file: [FILE-LINK](http://www.filedropper.com/exercise1)

Answer (score 0):

In the `Sort tab`, if you have State = "Auto Ascending" try to uncheck that and see if it helps.
//Micke

Comment: Unfortunately, it is the same. Any other suggestion?

Comment: Try sorting on the total minimum of Day_Order disregarding the selection of it: In Sort choose: Expression = min({1} Day_Order).

Comment: Silly thing, If it is checked ensure that the list box size is large enough to fit all the items in the list otherwise that will override the Auto Ascending option and always move the selected options to the top

Comment: @TheBudac: the list box is large enough. I uploaded the QVW and the link can be found in the question. I would appreciate if you could have a look.

Comment: @mickeger: could you also have a look at the QVW please?

Answer (score 0):

The reason it isn't working is because in initiation section (the variable set statements at the beginning of your script) you don't define the day names as the day names that your data has

```
SET DayNames='Mo;Di;Mi;Do;Fr;Sa;So';
SET LongDayNames='Montag;Dienstag;Mittwoch;Donnerstag;Freitag;Samstag;Sonntag';
```

To make that sorting work you need to have those values match. That said that method isn't 100% guaranteed to work so you can force it to work (or if you don't want to change those defaults because it looks like that is for your regional settings) by using the `dual()` function which assigns a number to the values in a field but displays the text. Essentially combining the 2 steps you wanted to do.

Your Capture Day will then look like this:

```
dual(CaptureDay, 
 If(CaptureDay = 'Monday', 1,
    If(CaptureDay = 'Tuesday', 2,
        If(CaptureDay = 'Wednesday', 3,
            If(CaptureDay = 'Thursday', 4,
                If(CaptureDay = 'Friday', 5,
                    If(CaptureDay = 'Saturday', 6,
                        If(CaptureDay = 'Sunday', 7, 8)
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
 )) as     CaptureDay,
```

Then your sort settings should look like this:

[image]

Comment: When I do it as you suggested, then the elements do not change places when I clck on them. However, the days are not alligned from Monday to Sunday in the right order.

Comment: Please replace your old file with the new one and I'll see what I can find